# vue.js: How to do calculation from object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects, vuetify.js

I have tried different approaches but I'm not getting the desired result. I want to get the total sum of the product answer from each array but I'm only getting for the first array. Here is the link to my full code on codepen.

https://codepen.io/Thinker95/pen/bGbOrJb

Below is my code:

```
Calculate(){
  this.fights[0].consumption = this.fights[0].rating*this.fights[0].quantity*this.fights[0].operation;
  this.answer = this.fights[0].consumption;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `this.fights[0]`, you only use the first fight.

You need to iterate over `fights` to set the consumption for each fight and compute `this.answer`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
      fights: [
        { device:'Laptop', rating:1000, quantity: 2, operation: 4, consumption: ''},
        { device:'Television', rating:900, quantity: 4, operation: 6, consumption: ''},
      ],
      answer: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Calculate(){
      this.answer = 0
      this.fights.forEach(fight => {
        fight.consumption =  fight.rating * fight.quantity * fight.operation
        this.answer += fight.consumption
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="fight in fights">
    <h3>{{ fight.device }}</h3>
    <p>Rating: {{ fight.rating }}</p>
    <p>Quantity: {{ fight.quantity }}</p>
    <p>Operation: {{ fight.operation }}</p>
    <p>Consumption: {{ fight.consumption }}</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <button @click="Calculate">calculate</button>
  {{ answer }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate only first element of the array.

You have to loop through it

Put this inside your calculate function

```
this.fights.forEach((fight)=>{
  this.fight.consumption = this.fight.rating*this.fight.quantity*this.fight.operation;
  this.answer += this.fight.consumption
})
```